# How to create power operation with regexparser?

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I'm building a simple calculator using Scala RegexParser and I was trying to create a rule for power operations using `**` as follows:

```scala
package com.pt.pedrorijo91.calc

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
import scala.math.pow

class Arith extends RegexParsers {

  def number: Parser[Double] = """\d+(\.\d*)?""".r ^^ { _.toDouble }

  def factor: Parser[Double] = number | "(" ~> expr <~ ")" | expr~"**"~expr ^^ { case x ~ "**" ~ y => pow(x,y)}

  def term  : Parser[Double] = factor ~ rep( "*" ~ factor | "/" ~ factor) ^^ {
    case number ~ list => list.foldLeft(number) {
      case (x, "*" ~ y) => x * y
      case (x, "/" ~ y) => x / y
    }
  }

  def expr  : Parser[Double] = term ~ rep("+" ~ term | "-" ~ term) ^^ {
    case number ~ list => list.foldLeft(number) {
      case (x, "+" ~ y) => x + y
      case (x, "-" ~ y) => x - y
    }
  }

}
```

I've inserted the power rule in `factor` method, but if I try to parse `"2 ** 3"` it enters in an infinite loop.

If instead of `expr~"\*\*"~expr` I use `number~"**"~number` I get a failure upon parsing with the following message:

> string matching regex `\d+(\.\d*)?' expected but`*' found

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Scala so it might be doing this dynamically, but how are you ensuring that you're grabbing groups (each number) as the expressions for which you are computing a power? I'd suggest trying `(\d+(\.\d)?).*(\d+(\.\d)?)` so that each number is in its own group.

Answer (score 2):

it seems scala's RegexParser builds recursive descent parsers.

the problem then is the underlying grammar of your parser does not belong to the class of grammars parseable with it (more formally, it is left recursive).

the production `factor -> epxr ** expr` makes your grammar left recursive (and ambigous).

you should add another level (non terminal symbol) to express that `**` has the highest precedence, and use only atomic expressions as its arguments to prevent ambigouities.

that'd be something like this

```
atomicexpr -> number | (expr)

factor -> atomicexpr ( ** atomicexpr )?
```

note that this way to combine succesive **s you'll be forced to add parentheses.